# Browsers in 2013 with Web MIDI API?

Tags: audio, web, midi, web-midi

Does anybody knows if there's a browser whith Web MIDI support? ... I've tried the samples on http://webaudio.github.io/web-midi-api/ but they throw me an error that my navigator has not such properties. Im working on google-chrome and firefox. If, there's no browsers that support MIDI, when do u estimate we will have one, maybe in the next 2 years?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this posting](http://www.html5audio.org/2013/06/web-midi-api-available-in-chrome-canary.html) (dated June 28th 2013), "initial experimental support" for Web MIDI is now available in Chrome Canary.

Comment: Version 31.0.1601.0 canary, says: "Uncaught TypError: Object has no method 'requestMIDI Access'."

Comment: Ok, I've done it. I just went to chrome://flags/#enable-web-midi 
and enable Web MIDI API. Now it's workin, thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

As of now, there are no browsers that support the Web MIDI API yet. First off, the spec isn't finalized yet and there were a couple of changes made from the original spec (function names and procedures could change anytime).

You can, however, enable your browser to support the API by installing the [Jazz plugin](http://jazz-soft.net/) and using Chris Wilson's [Web MIDI API shim](https://github.com/cwilso/WebMIDIAPIShim). I have personally tried it and it really works! :)

Answer (score 2):

As of writing this, Web Midi is now available in regular Chrome (not just canary), though it is still an experimental feature, so it must be enabled manually at chrome://flags/#enable-web-midi

Answer (score 1):

try this one, [jasmid](https://github.com/gasman/jasmid) to play midi files directly on chrome/ff, no plugin needed

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's often advisable to not answer questions that ask for recommendations about tools to use, plugins, etc. as these can often be opinion based and don't provide help with how to actually use these. As well, these questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow and can be subject to downvoting from more "negative" voters. You might want to take a look at the [help], which has a topic on what is and isn't on-topic on Stack Overflow. Thank you, and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

One of the authors of the Web MIDI API has created this shim, which enables you to work with the Web MIDI API in today’s browsers:

WebMIDIAPIShim
https://github.com/cwilso/WebMIDIAPIShim

Comment: Thank you very much, but I mean without plugins.